# Gulp: Is there any difference with .on('change') and without?

Tags: gulp, task, watch

Is there any difference between:

```
gulp.watch("src/sass/**/*.{scss,sass}").on("change", gulp.series("style"));
```

and

```
gulp.watch("src/sass/**/*.{scss,sass}", gulp.series("style"));
```

?

Looks like it work the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more events that can be watched, see [chokidar watch events](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/watch#chokidar-instance).

In my testing if I use

```
gulp.watch("src/sass/**/*.{scss,sass}").on("change", gulp.series("style"));
```

the task will **not** trigger if I add folders or files or copy a file into a pre-existing folder that is being watched (probably also deleting - I just didn't test that).

If I use

```
gulp.watch("src/sass/**/*.{scss,sass}", gulp.series("style"));
```

all the above - adding and copying events do trigger the task.  So apparently, not specifying a watch event is the same as specifying `on("all", ...)`.  Which is probably what you want unless you want different behaviour when you add, delete or copy  a file vs. when you modify an existing one.  The events just give you more fine-grained control.